# Missing Libsodium in WSL2

Tags: wsl-2, libsodium, magento2.4

Where can I find lib-sodium files in WSL2 or where should I install lib-sodium in WSL2 it is giving me the error (php8.1)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVYgC.png)

What should i do to solve this error

I install libsodium-1.0.18.tar.gz in my opt > lampp > bin folder but it didn't work!